# Obtaining MongoDb ObjectId in Node in ASCII

Tags: node.js, mongodb

On querying a MongoDb database via the `mongo` CLI (v3.0.7), documents and their ObjectIds are returned looking like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566ef12723b89d23fa5003fe"),
  "address": "30 Pair Road",
  ...
}
```

But performing a similar search using the Node MongoDb library (mongodb@2.0.52, mongodb-core@1.2.28) returns:

```
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'Vnñ\'#¸#úP\u0003þ' },
  address: '30 Pair Road',
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to convert the `id` value of `'Vnñ\'#¸#úP\u0003þ'` back into the 24 hexadecimal characters of `"566ef12723b89d23fa5003fe"` so that I can query the database by it (as querying with an _id of 'Vnñ\'#¸#úP\u0003þ' obviously doesn't work).

The later call includes a call to `toArray` on the cursor returned from the collection which I guess is partially deserialising the ObjectId instance.

****edit****

I put in a logging statement into the function accepting the result from `toArray` which showed:

```
{ _id : 566ef12723b89d23fa5003fe,
  address: "30 Pair Road",
  ...
}
```

The garbled value I was seeing is coming from two locations.  One in the node debug repl:

```
> users[0]
{ _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'Vnñ\'#¸#úP\u0003þ' ... }
> users[0]._id.toString()
'567b1a7d818d826f1dab9c6f'
> users[0]._id.id.toString()
'Vnñ\'#¸#úP\u0003þ'
```

And then secondly when I was serialising it.  I am now calling `toString` explicitly on the _id field and it's behaving correctly.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that produces that output?

Comment: @JohnnyHK done.  I've located the "issue" still a bit confused though.